# Show stream video in angular 8 with HTML5 Player

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to open the player mode when the user clicks on the Preview button so that the user can watch the selected movie or song by downloading and streaming.

Now the question is, do I have to download the file first and then convert it to a secure address and put it on `[src]` so that the user can watch the movie stream or I pass the direct Address the file from server to player for download and stream ???

I write this code but it not show me any thing .

HTML :

```
<audio controls>
   <source [src]="fileSource" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

TS :

```
 fileSource: any;

ngOnInit(): void {
if (typeof this.data.src === 'number') {
  this.getImageFromService();
  }
}

     createImageFromBlob(image: Blob): void {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
      this.fileSource = reader.result;
    }, false);

    if (image) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    }
  }

  getImageFromService(): void {

    this.isLoading = true;
    this.postFileService.downloadFile(this.data.src).subscribe(data => {
      this.createImageFromBlob(data);
      this.isLoading = false;
    }, error => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      console.log(error);
    });
  }



downloadFile(id: number): Observable<Blob> {
    const URL = `${this.appConfig.apiEndpoint + '/PostFileContent/DownloadFile/' + id}`;

    return this.http.get(URL, { responseType: 'blob' });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass direct address from the server inside source.

Comment: i need send token with url . how can i solve this ?

Comment: @kianousjdortaj use an token in the URL/cookies. This allows the browser to load the parts of the file it needs, rather than having to download the whole file before showing it to the user (make sure to support the `accept-ranges` header in the back end

Comment: @Ferrybig Please guide me more

Comment: @Ferrybig how can i so this ?

Comment: import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';

getLoggedInUser(auth_token): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': auth_token
    })
    return this.http.get(apiUrl, { headers: headers })
  }

you can do something like this

And do not forget to call and subscribe in your Component.